# Confusion about React componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree).

if i append a blue div in componentDidMount, i would see original react component at first, then i see the blue div. but i see the blue div directly even not a blink.

Why? Is the browser is too fast and my eyes too insensitive？

---

```
  .blue {
     position:absolute;
     top:0
     height:100px;
     width:100vw;
     background:blue
    }
***

classclass App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const div=document.createElement('div');
    div.className='blue';
    document.body.appendChild(div)
  }
  render(){  
   return (
     <div style={{background:'red'}}>hello world</div>
   )
  }
}
```

Comment: Check it using a countdowntimer!!!

Comment: Any specific reason you are directly modifying DOM inside of React?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working as desired. It first renders red then it adds a blue div. It's happening because there are no function calls that need to wait. Also, the rendering that you are doing is so light that it executes effortlessly with minimal time.

You can verify your execution behaviour using two ways

1. Inspect the dom tree
2. Use debugger and stop execution at `render()`.

For example
    `render() { debugger; return (<div></div>);}`. It'll halt your execution, and then you can proceed step by step using browser debugging capabilities.

3. If you're using Chrome, by navigating to the `Sources` tab and marking a breakpoint on your desired file.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer to @Aseem Upadhyay's good debugging one here is one more with avoiding manipulating the DOM directly and using React's state.

```js
    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        style: {
          position: "absolute",
          top: "0",
          height: "100px",
          width: "100vw",
          background: "red",
        }
      }
      
      componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState( prevState => ({
          style: {
            ...prevState.style, background: "blue"
          }
        })), 2000 );
        
      }
      render(){
        return (
          <div style={this.state.style}>hello world</div>
        )
      }
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById("app")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Also you can use [React Developer Tools](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html) and inspect the DOM and state changes easily if you write your app with the React way.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your eyes. Any logic you place inside of `componentDidMount()` will execute the instant your application boots up.

That means that if I define a function inside of my class, underneath the `constructor()` but above the `render()` method. If I define a method called `componentDidMount()`, this function will be automatically called one time, when the component first gets rendered onto the screen.

After the `componentDidMount()` method gets called our component will sit around and wait for an update which will come in the form of calling a `setState()` method. Anytime we call `setState()` and update our state, the component will re render or update itself. When that happens, another component called `componentDidUpdate()` will be called automatically.

To better understand this, inside of your component try this:

```
.blue {
     position:absolute;
     top:0
     height:100px;
     width:100vw;
     background:blue
    }
***

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('My component was rendered to the screen’);
  }
  render(){  
   return (
     <div style={{background:'red'}}>hello world</div>
   )
  }
}
```

You will immediately see the string logged to your browsers console anytime your component shows up on the screen.

Also, you have declared `class` keyword twice, you must be getting an error about that, remove one of them and last but certainly not least, notice how I have passed `props` to both `constructor()` method and `super()`?

When we define the `constructor()` method, it will automatically be called with the `props` object. Once we use the `constructor()` we have to also add `super(props)` as well. You must be getting on error on this as well, fix it.